# Flea markets in the New York City area

Tags: budget, new-york-city, shopping

It is always fun to visit flea markets when travelling. What are the major options for doing this in the New York City area? We may consider travelling (preferrably by public transportation) around an hour to such a spot. (Staying in Union City right across the river.)

Comment: How big of an for you is New York City Area?

Comment: good point. updated the question!

Comment: What do you intend to use to get around?

Comment: commuting? public transportation!

Comment: Some commute using a car.

Comment: also a good point!

Comment: You should consider the entire city to be one big flea market

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using public transportation your pretty much only bet is visiting New York City, Jersey City, or Hoboken.  Everything else you might need to get a car.

If you do a quick search on the map of [Manhattan](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=flea+market&ll=40.75584,-73.98365&spn=0.210134,0.278435&sll=40.714353,-74.005973&sspn=0.841062,1.113739&near=New+York,+NY&geocode=CZNTLAHSBDbTFXFAbQIdK8KW-yk7CD_TpU_CiTFi_nfhBo8LyA&hq=flea+market&t=m&z=12&iwloc=C) you will get quite a few.  There are larger ones like:

- [Hells Kitchen Flea Market](http://www.hellskitchenfleamarket.com/home/)
- [Brooklyn Flea](http://www.brooklynflea.com/)

And quite a few smaller ones listed.